# Rails 3.1 odbc adapter exists? Trying to connect to an iSeries through ODBC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got this rails app that need to feed (poll) from an iSeries source.

As far as now, I'v got an odbc connection working as stand alone (tested using isql).

I've noticed that all odbc adapters for activerecord are for Rails 2.

So, is there a gem that has odbc functionality for activerecord on Rails 3.1?

BTW, beside odbc, can AR connect to iSeries directly?